# Can't install Flask-Bcrypt: `libffi` is missing

Tags: python

I try to install [Flask-Bcrypt](https://flask-bcrypt.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) on Raspbian to hash passwords in my Flask application, but I get this error:

```
Searching for flask-bcrypt
Best match: Flask-Bcrypt 0.7.1
Flask-Bcrypt 0.7.1 is already the active version in easy-install.pth

Using /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Processing dependencies for flask-bcrypt
Searching for bcrypt
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/bcrypt/
Best match: bcrypt 2.0.0
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/b/bcrypt/bcrypt-2.0.0.tar.gz#md5=e7fb17be46904cdb2ae6a062859ee58c
Processing bcrypt-2.0.0.tar.gz
Running bcrypt-2.0.0/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-EkuzN4/bcrypt-2.0.0/egg-dist-tmp-bQofuP
Checking .pth file support in .
/usr/bin/python -E -c pass
Searching for cffi>=1.1
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/cffi/
Best match: cffi 1.2.1
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/c/cffi/cffi-1.2.1.tar.gz#md5=faca1e420e80433db409bb1bdd0a3f45
Processing cffi-1.2.1.tar.gz
Running cffi-1.2.1/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-EkuzN4/bcrypt-2.0.0/temp/easy_install-eyecOZ/cffi-1.2.1/egg-dist-tmp-ismXiX
Package libffi was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libffi.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'libffi' found
Package libffi was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libffi.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'libffi' found
Package libffi was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libffi.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'libffi' found
Package libffi was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libffi.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'libffi' found
Package libffi was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libffi.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'libffi' found
compiling '_configtest.c':
__thread int some_threadlocal_variable_42;

gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -c _configtest.c -o _configtest.o
success!
removing: _configtest.c _configtest.o
c/_cffi_backend.c:13:17: fatal error: ffi.h: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
compilation terminated.
error: Setup script exited with error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Can I add `libffi`? How? Should I use another library to hash passwords?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Python needs the native C lib installed.  Since it is building against it, it also needs the development headers, which presuming you are using Raspbian or another Debian variant, come in `-dev` packages.  These will pull in the library itself as a dependency if not installed.

This is from Raspbian 8 (aka. jessie):

```
> apt-cache search libffi | grep dev
libffi-dev - Foreign Function Interface library (development files)
libffindex0-dev - library for simple index/database for huge amounts of small files (development)
libffi5-dev - Foreign Function Interface library (development files)
```

There are your choices; presumably the middle one is unrelated.  Since there's a `libffi6` runtime, likely the non-5 dev is for that and 6 is the default.  So I'd first try:

```
apt-get install libffi-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

stretch doesn't seem to contain this by default, but I searched the debian repositories and they have versions compiled for armhf. I just downloaded libffi-dev for armhf and installed it manually with dpkg